# Threading in C++/CLI, CLR

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, clr

Faced a problem. Need to call a class member method on a separate thread C++/CLI

.h:

```
ref class BgWorker
{
private:
    void MainLoop();
public:
    void Start();
};
```

.cpp:

```
void BgWorker::MainLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        ...    
    }
}

void BgWorker::Start()
{
    System::Threading::Thread^ td = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(MainLoop); // v1; didn't working
    System::Threading::Thread^ td = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(MainLoop)); // v2; didn't
    System::Threading::Thread^ td = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &MainLoop)); // v3; didn't

    std::thread td(MainLoop); // v4, didn't
}
```

Also tried via `System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler()`, most likely i did something wrong

I want to use this constructor, but I can't pull out a link to MainLoop:

```
public : Thread(System::Threading::ThreadStart^ start)
```

Same problem with standard stream `std::thread`, MainLoop is not a function reference

I couldn't find anything on my question on google. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: The ThreadStart delegate takes *two* arguments, there `this` and `&BgWorker::MainLoop`.  Use the [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here's what I did:

BgWorker.h:

```cpp
ref class BgWorker
{
    public:
        void MainLoop();
}
```

BgWorker.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "BgWorker.h"

void BgWorker::MainLoop()
{
    ...
}
```

myProgramm.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "BgWorker.h"

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    BgWorker^bg = gcnew BgWorker();
    System::Threading::Thread^ ml = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(bg, &BgWorker::MainLoop));
    ml->Name = "MainLoop";
    ml->Start();
}
```

It's not exactly what I wanted (didn't want to manage threads in main), but for starters, it's a great result. I also had to get rid of the now unnecessary `BgWorker::Start()` function.

Аnd yet, if someone knows how to start a new thread managed by an internal ref class method, I would be very happy with an example.

EDITED

Many thanks to [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt); it this question just looks ridiculously easy now

With the first structure:

```
void BgWorker::Start()
{
    System::Threading::Thread^ ml = gcnew System::Threading::Thread(gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(this, &BgWorker::MainLoop));
    ml->Name = "MainLoop";
    ml->Start();
}
```

This question can be closed now.

Comment: The original code structure would have worked fine, your new solution is almost exactly the same as original #2, except that now you are (1) providing the target object and (b) properly qualifying the name of the member function.  Fix #2 to do that and it will work.